# Joomla Logman Notify modify email message

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, notify, logman

A question about the joomla plugin Logman Notify. (https://www.joomlatools.com/extensions/logman/documentation/plugins/notify-plugin)
The Notify plugin can send activity notifications to a selected group of email addresses such as a new published article.
Author name, the action (created) and the link to the article in the admin editor are displayed in the email.
I want to modify the language/text in this email
But I can not find the key or code for this.
There are many keys (in .ini files) in different files but none are linked to the email text.
Besides I want the url in the email to the new page on the frontend website.

I want to edit whole body: Text, language and the link.

I searched in language files, searched keys in joomla language to override the content of the keys and searched code files.

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.